# How to compare degree of invariance (with words)?

Tags: definition, transformation, word-problem

Invariance is the property of *a function, quantity, or property which remains unchanged when a specified transformation is applied.*

How would I say that one function varies less than another after a specific transformation is applied?
E.g. is there a better way than:

> *"f is more scale invariant than g."*

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that this was well-defined.  Are you more concerned about average errors or worst errors?  And how are you defining error in the first place?

Comment: So, concretely I am extracting signals which can have different scales, and one method is highly sensitive to the scale of the signal and the other isn't. There in't an explicit error measure

Comment: Right, well absent explicit measures it's just subjective.  Which isn't to say that you can't define things along your subjective lines, but there is no absolute notion here.  For instance...$0 $ is constant.  $f(x)=0 +\epsilon(x)$ where $\epsilon (x)$ is noise (always less that $10^{-10}$ in magnitude say). isn't constant but it sure is close.  $g(x)=0 $ except that $g(0)=10^{10}$ only fails to be constant at one point but it is dramatically non-constant at that point.  Which is closer to constant?

Comment: What is usually done in cases like this is to define some sort of error measure.  Doesn't have to be perfect in any sense, it just has to capture a large part of what you are after.  Then you can define approximations in terms of your error measure.  For instance, in regressions it is standard to use a least squares sort of error.  That has some very nice properties (and it is analytically very tractable) but other error measures are good too.  Straight absolute difference, for instance, often captures a fit better.  This is all more Art than Science.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As is I don't have any ground truth to compare but I will try and find an error measure.

Comment: In curve modeling (for Finance, say) the error functions are complex and often have unspecified parameters.  One wants the curve to fit the data, true, but you also want the curve to "look right", i.e. you want it to not have odd local corners and curvature.  So your error function will have terms measuring accuracy and geometric coherence,  How should those terms be balanced?  Well....who knows? In practice, you define a weighted sum and you look at optimal solutions for various weights...choose the weights that way.  Like I say, more Art than Science.